# FTP issue when using File.Move - C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm experiencing an issue with an FTP watcher service and the File.Move method.

The FTP server is a simple IIS 8.5 FTP site and the FTP client is FileZilla FTP Client

The windows service will poll a directory where the files are to be dropped.

The first task is to rename the file, using the static File.Move method.
The second, is to copy the file to another directory using the static File.Copy method.

The issue is that while the file is being transferred, the File.Copy will [correctly] throw an IO Exception if it is used, with the message "The file is being used by another process".

However the File.Move will perform it's task without throwing any exception while the file is still being transferred. Is this the correct behavior for this method? I've not been able to find any information on why this occurs. My impression was that the File.Move would throw an exception if it's used on a file that's being used by another process [The FTP Transfer] but it doesn't seem to.

Has anyone experienced this and / or have an explanation for the behavior of the File.Move method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying a file requires opening it for read access. The FTP server currently has the file open such that you cannot open it for reading.

Moving a file does not require opening it for read access unless the file is on a different volume than the destination.

Since moving a file to the same volume requires only delete access and not read access, the FTP server must lock the files for read and write, but not delete.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows that File.Move will indeed throw an exception if the file is in use when you try to move it, so I think your premise is incorrect.

```
var filePath = @"d:\public\temp\temp.txt";
var moveToPath = @"d:\public\temp\temp2.txt";

// Create a stream reader so the file is 'in use'
using (var fileStream = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    // This will fail with an IO exception
    File.Move(filePath, moveToPath);
}
```

Exception:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a file is effectively implemented as a mere rename and only requires write permission on the target and source directory. For a real copy you need read permissions on the file itself. As there is an exclusive lock on the source file, the copy will fail, however, the move will succeed.

Comment: The way I read the question, it is the server where the problem is happening, not the client, so FileZilla is uninvolved.